# Build a Generalised Regression Model Containing Linear and Non- Linear Predictor Variables with a Target Variable

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, nonlinear-regression

Imagine a dataset having 5 predictor variables and a target variable, through scatter plot I observed three predictor variables having a linear relationship with the target variable and the other two having a nonlinear relationship. How can I build a Generalized Linear Regression model in such a way that the non-linearity of the two variables is explained along with Linear Relationship of the other three variables?

Answer (score 2):

I believe the R mgcv package will allow you to do this, i.e. fit a GAM with a mix of smooths (spline terms) and linear terms. For example

y ~ dm  + af + s(BMI)

builds a model with two linear terms (dm and af) and one non-linear (BMI).

Comment: You can also use `glm` with regression splines